# TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, constants, setstate

This is my code:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
var name = (cookies.get('name'));
var key = (cookies.get('key'));
console.log(key);
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: amber,
    secondary: blue
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  bottomView: {

    width: '25%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0
  },
});
class Base {
  constructor() {}
}

class Homework extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      topicBox: null,
      payloadBox: null
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
 publish(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  } 


  async loadTest() {
    try {
      //grab courses
      const response = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?access_token=' + key);
      const json = await response.json();
      //coursemax vars will eventually be user defined
      var coursemax = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

      if (json.courses != null) {
        for (var course = 0; course < json.courses.length && course < 9; course++) {
          //grab course info
          var coursework = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/' + json.courses[course].id + '/courseWork?access_token=' + key);
          var coursejson = await coursework.json();
          console.log(coursejson);
          var assignment = "";
          for (var assignmentnum in coursejson.courseWork) {
            if (assignmentnum <= coursemax[course] - 1) {
              //add in assignment
              assignment += "<p>" + coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].title + "</p>";
              //"Due: "+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.month+"/"+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.day
            }
          }
          //making ids to render
          document.getElementById('class' + (course + 1) + 'info').innerHTML = assignment;
          document.getElementById('class' + (course + 1)).innerHTML = json.courses[course].name + '</b>' + ':' + '<br/>';;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
var app = new Homework();
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.loadTest();

function publish() {
  console.log(this.state.topicBox, this.state.payloadBox);
  const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
  const item = {
    title: this.state.topicBox,
    user: this.state.payloadBox
  }
  itemsRef.push(item).set("name");
  this.setState({
    topicBox: '',
    payloadBox: ''
  });

}

const LoginPage = () =>
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static" id='title'>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography type="title" color='inherit'>
              MVHS Homework App
            </Typography>
            <div id='avatar' color='inherit'><Avatar>{name[0]}</Avatar></div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="topicBox" 
        placeholder="Name" 
        value={ this.state.topicBox }
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="payloadBox" 
        placeholder="Details"
        value={ this.state.payloadBox } 
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" style = {theme.bottomView} onClick={ this.publish }>
        Secondary
      </Button>
      </div>

    </MuiThemeProvider>



export default LoginPage
```

In the code above, there is an error on:

> this.setState({value: event.target.value});

And the Error is:

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Why is this happening?

***EDIT:*** The error I believe is the only issue with the code right now. Feel free to tell me if any more errors. :) (Am I nor establishing the car correctly?)

> ***EDIT:*** Will this code sent a value with the edited text inputs to the database?

Comment: the error is because `function publish` does not have access to `this` and thereby access to `setState`. That should be inside a react class.

Comment: extend `Component`, not a base class and yes, you have bigger issues

Comment: What other issues?

Comment: Will this code send a value with the edited text inputs to the database? @BoyWithSilverWings

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing? You don't need to call functions like make proper use of state lifting `props`. Learn new ES6 arrow function and lexical `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend your Homework with Component. And also you are trying to set the state with the unknown key called "value"

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
class Homework extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      topicBox: null,
      payloadBox: null
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  publish(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value});  // this will set your state of current input, that you were handling
    //this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value}) 
    //this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

   render(){
     return(
       // your code
       <div>
         <LoginPage handleChange={this.state.handleChange} publish={this.state.publish} topicBox={this.state.topicBox} payloadBox={this.state.payloadBox}  />
       </div>
     )
   } 
}
```

This is your functional component, in that you are trying to change your state. You can't change the state directly from here inside the functional component. Indeed you can pass the functions (handleChange and publish) as a prop to the functional component(LoginPage). you may use the below links as reference https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stateful-vs-stateless-functional-components-in-react--cms-29541

```
// here you can access the function as props. ie the Homework component passed its state such as topicBox, payloadBox, handleChange function and publish function as a props to LoginPage functional component. Here you can access it by using  props.handleChange (which is the prop name mentioned in Homework component)

export const LoginPage = (props) =>
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static" id='title'>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography type="title" color='inherit'>
              MVHS Homework App
            </Typography>
            <div id='avatar' color='inherit'><Avatar>{name[0]}</Avatar></div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="topicBox" 
        placeholder="Name" 
        value={ props.topicBox }
        onChange={ props.handleChange } 
      />
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="payloadBox" 
        placeholder="Details"
        value={ props.payloadBox } 
        onChange={ props.handleChange } 
      />
      <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" style = {theme.bottomView} onClick={props.publish }>
        Secondary
      </Button>
      </div>

    </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: when I change the text box i get the error that e is not defined. @Jeeva

Comment: When I update the text I get this error. `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the component.`

Comment: @Jim Hall, you cannot set state for the stateless component which is your functional component, indeed you can pass the props for it

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you try as like above

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` on this line:  
`value={ this.state.topicBox } 
`  @Jeeva

Comment: I get there error of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined' on the same line @Jeeva

Comment: @Jim Hall, sorry for the inconvenience. Actually the 'this' will not be used in the functional component, as we passed the props for LoginPage functional component. So we can able access it as follows, props.handleChange. use like this and let me know if any.

Comment: Its says props is undefined! @Jeeva